# PHP: How to do a SOAP request from this XML?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soapheader

Can someone help me?

I can not perform the AdvogadoRegular function in this web service.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:int="https://www5.oab.org.br/integracao/">
   <soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
      <token xmlns="http://CFOAB.Integracao">xxxxxxxx</token>
      <wsa:To>https://www5.oab.org.br/Integracao/CNA.svc</wsa:To>
   </soap:Header>  
   <soap:Body>
      <int:AdvogadoRegular>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <int:cpf>99999999999</int:cpf>
      </int:AdvogadoRegular>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I try to access from that code.

```
// WSDL
$client = new SoapClient('https://www5.oab.org.br/Integracao/CNA.svc?wsdl', $options = array(
                                                                            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
                                                                            'trace'=>1, 
                                                                            'exceptions'=> 0
            ));

// NOME DA FUNÇÃO A SER EXECUTADA
$function = 'AdvogadoRegular';

// PARÂMETROS DA FUNÇÃO A SER EXECUTADA
$arguments= array('AdvogadoRegular' => array( 'cpf'  => '99999999999' ));

// URL DO WEB SERVICE
$options = array('location' => 'https://www5.oab.org.br/Integracao/CNA.svc');


// HEADER
$token = array(
    'token'=> 'xxxxxxxx',
    'wsa:To'=>'https://www5.oab.org.br/Integracao/CNA.svc',

);
$header = new SoapHeader("http://CFOAB.Integracao",'token',$token,false);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);



// EXECUTA A FUNÇÃO
$result = $client->__soapCall($function, $arguments, $options);

echo $result;
```

I think the error happens when I try to send the header. Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

first I would advise you to use a WSDL to php generator such as [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator), then regarding your header, it seems it's a WsSecurity header that you have to send, so you should try using the [WsSecurity](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/WsSecurity) project that eases the way to add this type of header